# OpenVPN - allow access to only one server in the network

Tags: openvpn

is it possible to block a user's access to every server / IP except one specific server once he is logged in by OpenVPN, and how can I implement that?

The other users should not be affected by this restriction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you use x.509 certificates for every different user, you are able to assign a unique ip addresse from the openvpn remote ip pool. See option `--ifconfig-pool-persist file` in [OpenVPN 2.2 Manual](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/manuals/427-openvpn-22.html) .

After this, you are able to use iptables as usual.

Comment: `--ifconfig-push` might be more appropriate as it provides a guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the repository https://github.com/dmytro/openvpn_restrict

It uses `learn-address` configuration option of OpenVPN to start IPTables script on connect/disconnect by client. Client is detected by CN of the certificate.

Add 2 lines to OpenVPN config:

`learn-address /etc/openvpn/connect
client-disconnect /etc/openvpn/connect`

and add script and configuration file as described in the README.

Answer (score -1):

If your openvpn is configured to use routing not bridging you can do this by pushing them only a host route /32 based on the certificate they send. The openvpn sample configuration has an example of how you can set this up.

Comment: Just pushing a specific route will not prevent the user from accessing other hosts. This user could still add the correct route to its computer and access those servers. The only way to prevent an access is by using the server firewall.